# Access grab state of evdev device

Tags: kernel, memory, kernel-modules, devices, input

I need to retrieved the grab state of an evdev device in a program. More specifically, I need to retrieve the state of the `grab` pointer in the `evdev` struct seen here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/drivers/input/evdev.c#L42 (if it is NULL or not NULL). Is this at all possible from userspace, e.g. through reading kernel memory with /dev/(k)mem or do I need to write a kernel module? Where should I get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether a device is currently grabbed, from userspace, you can try to grab it yourself; either using the `EVIOCGRAB` `ioctl` yourself, or `libevdev_grab` in `libevdev`:

```
if (!ioctl(evdevfd, EVIOCGRAB, (void *) 1)) {
    // We grabbed the device, no one else had it; release it
    ioctl(evdevfd, EVIOCGRAB, (void *) 0);
} else if (errno == EBUSY) {
    // The device is busy, someone else has it
} else {
    // Something else went wrong
}
```

or

```
struct libevdev *dev;
libevdev_new_from_fd(evdevfd, &dev);
if (!libevdev_grab(dev, LIBEVDEV_GRAB)) {
    // We grabbed the device, no one else had it; release it
    libevdev_grab(dev, LIBEVDEV_UNGRAB);
} else if (errno == EBUSY) {
    // The device is busy, someone else has it
} else {
    // Something else went wrong
}
```

(Sprinkle liberally with error-handling; `evdevfd` is the open file descriptor for the evdev device you’re interested in.)